# Import com.apple.com.dnssd package

Tags: java, bonjour

I'm trying to compile and run a sample bonjour program apple provides in the BonjourSDK found here:
http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/index.html

The program is called SimpleChat.java. However, whenever I attempt to compile the program I get this error:
"SimpleChat.java:55: package com.apple.dnssd does not exist"

I can't for the life of me fine the necessary file that contains this package. I must be missing something simple, but can't figure it out. I just installed JDK 1.6, but that's not helping. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your error looks suspiciously like the one in this mail thread:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/Bonjour-dev/2006/Jul/msg00046.html

Are you building on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling in Windows.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest seeing if you need to build the java api. :-)